# Can I name 2 subsequent columns identical like the previous one? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in Excel and some columns are unnamed there:
A_ColumnWithName, Unnamed1, Unnamed2, B_ColumnWithName, Unnamed3, Unnamed4

I need to set the names of the currently unnamed columns to the same as the 1st column name from the left, so my columns should look like this:

```
A_ColumnWithName, A_ColumnWithName, A_ColumnWithName, B_ColumnWithName, B_ColumnWithName, B_ColumnWithName
```

Any hints how can I do it using Python?
An important thing is that there is tons of such columns that's why it's required to do so in the most automatic way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the index to Series and use it to `mask` the names that contain "Unnamed" and `ffill` the previous valid name:

```
cols = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = cols.mask(cols.str.contains('Unnamed')).ffill()
```

*Note however that having duplicated columns names is **not** encouraged*

example input:

```
   A Unnamed1 Unnamed2  B Unnamed3  C
0  x        x        x  x        x  x
```

output:

```
   A  A  A  B  B  C
0  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code would work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( columns= ["A_ColumnWithName", "unnamed","unnamed", "B_ColumnWithName", "unnamed", "unnamed"])

replaceWith = df.columns.values[0]
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    if df.columns[i] == 'unnamed':
        df.columns.values[i] = replaceWith
    else:
        replaceWith = df.columns.values[i]
```

Comment: True, thank you, but the thing is that there is plethora of such columns and I was wondering if it's possible to do it more automatically without typing all the column names. Do you know?

Comment: I have changed the code. Does it help?